# How to migrate anything on a postgres upgrade?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to upgrade from `postgres` 9.4 to 9.5

How can I ensure that all configuration, tables, data, userroles etc are also merged to the new version? Like:

- postgres.conf
- pg_hba.conf
- tablespaces
- user roles
- any databases, schemas, any data, any sequences, indexes, constraints etc

Would I have to do this manually?

Comment: For the .conf files you need to migrate them yourself (9.5 has introduced some new parameters and has removed some others). For anything that is _stored_ in the database, `pg_upgrade` will take care of that.

Comment: I've indeed never heard of this, neither found this during research on how to migrate easily. Thanks there's a guideline: https://www.arencambre.com/blog/2014/12/24/postgress-pg_upgrade-on-windows-the-documentation-misses-a-lot/

Comment: It's documented in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html

Comment: Can I run `pg_upgrade` without the `postgres` user on `windows`? I have none, and no rights to create one... When I run the `cmd` with my current logged in user (that has permissions on all postgres dirs of course), I'm getting the message `cannot write to log file pg_upgrade_internal.log`.

Comment: `pg_upgrade` needs to use the **database** (super)user `postgres`. You don't need a Windows user `postgres`. And of course your current Windows user needs to be able to read and write in the data directory of the Postgres installation .

Comment: I'm use the default `postgres/postgres` database user. Anyways running `RUNAS /USER:postgres “CMD.EXE”` gives me an error that the user does not exist.

Comment: "*cannot write to log file pg_upgrade_internal.log*" means your current Windows user isn't allowed to write in the current directory (or the data directory not sure about that)

Comment: Oh you where right. My own user didn't have full permissions on the pg folder.

Comment: Hm there is still the following problem: when running pg_upgrade, it tried to find the database role user with the same name as the windows user. As my windows user is named `membersound`, but the postgres user is `postgres`, this fails with error `connection to database failed: role 'membersound' does not exist`. And I have no windows user `postgres`.

Comment: Ok solved it appending `--username postgres`.